# Why was Post #15149 "Chrome has issues" Removed?

Tags: support, moderation

The guy asked legitimate question about the problem his site is facing when viewed in Chrome, something that happens all the time to all of us.

I have found the answer and posted it.
He was very happy, thanked me, accepted the answer, and even someone upvoted it.
Then came you moderators, 4 of you (didn't write which ones), obviosly voted to put question [on-hold], thus killing my 25 points I have rightfully earned.
Then someone even deleted the post.

Why did that happen? Please explain it to me. We can't all be terrific developers and coders, there are many of us quite happy to be skillfull integrators, and our knowledge and experience still can help many of users.

This way I feel like a moron, who wasted his time to help someone, and I'm seriosuly thinking about leaving JSX. This is quite ridicilous.

Comment: Hi Mirko, it's harsh when you put work into a perfectly good answer and the question is deemed unsuitable. I can't fix that for you but I can upvote your other good answers, of which there are many. ;)

Comment: Your post wasn't deleted because of anything you did or the quality of your answer, it was because the question itself was not fit for this site. In time I think you will come to understand what is suitable and what isn't. Please don't take the loss of points personally. Remember you helped the poster, so it wasn't a waste of time :) I hope you continue to help out at JSE and come to accept and understand the decision.

Comment: @moomoochoo Thank you, I understand everything now, I've even acepted answer, and added comment that I consider this matter closed... I really, really don't want anyone to bother with this matter anymore. I think I will delete the whole question, don't think it's viable to begin with. If I could, I would revert asking it anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mirko, thanks for your feedback and that you for trying to help others.

Below is the post you are referring to.

[image: Deleted post]

JSE is community driven and mostly self-moderated. The role of the moderators is to keep an eye on what is going on. There are 3 moderators (myself included) and we generally review questions which seem to have problems. Questions usually get closed by fellow JSE members, not by moderators.

Yes, occasionally a question might get deleted if it is not salvageable. Yes, your reputation goes away. Sorry about that - do not take it personally. It is hard to keep everybody happy. If you are a dedicated member I am sure you will manage to gain enough reputation.

Also please understand that JSE is not a forum and, while helping others is great, some questions just don't fit the vision most of us have. We are generally are looking for Joomla specific questions, questions which are very good formulated and researched.

Looking forward anytime for your feedback.

We are all passionate about Joomla and are here to build a quality community. And we certainly need your help!

Comment: I already said I will not waste my or others time on this matter. I do consider it closed. Doesn't matter what I think about it. Sorry to bother you, it wont happen again. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, let me clear up that it **wasn't** any of the moderators that voted to *close* the question. Putting a question on hold does not remove any reputation. You lost the reputation because the question was deleted.

If you're only complaining because of the 25 points you've lost for an answer, then I'm sure you can get those points back on a different question.

It was closed because it was simply a "my website is screwed on a specific browser, why?" type of question, with no evidence of research. In addition to that, the OP should primarily be contacting the developer of the template so they can fix it if need be.

On JSE, we're trying to get decent questions that other users can refer to if they have the same problem, and the question you're referring to did not fit into that category. Of course, that's my personal opinion, however others obviously felt the same way.

---

**May I also quote your first comment below his question:**

*Man, no one here has a mind-reading capabilites! You either be more specific with your questions, or try to show some researh effort on your own. JSX doesn't work like Quiz-Show*

---

You yourself even stated that the OP should show some research effort of their own.

Comment: Yes, I did "complain" as you nicely put it, but I answered the question later on. In the other words, we should not waste our time trying to help fellow Joomlers, we should know better, or ask someone which question to answer, and which not. Very tough indeed... I am obviously wasting my time answering, I should only read answers of great JSX-ers

Comment: If you feel this strongly about the matter, I'd suggest taking it up with a moderator and get the question "undeleted". I've simply given you my personal view on the matter, but that's all I have the power to do.

Comment: Thank you, I will not waste my or others time on this matter... And I'm not that "cheap" to complain about loosing 25 points, I just complained about dissing my time and effort... Never mind...

Comment: @Mikan the quality of questions that are posted on JSX will be determined by the feedback and support we provide. If poorly worded questions receive absolute silence, then people will think that there is no value in this community.  If people receive working solutions from poorly worded questions, they will never put more effort into future questions -- they think that they are doing what is expected. Volunteers that can offer constructive feedback to the OP which guides the posters to improve their question ONLY servers to benefit everyone. This is the frontline of making this place great.